# IPtables redirect /port forwading question problems

Tags: firewall, iptables, redirect, port

Im trying to setup a transparent proxy using IPtables but im not having much luck.

What I was hoping to do was forward all outgoing traffic to port 9040 and block everything else. Any ideas?

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner Mark -m tcp -j REDIRECT --to-ports 9040 

iptables -A OUTPUT -m --uid-owner Mark -j DROP
```

I receive the following error -

> (WARNING): UDP write to
>   68.32.239.182:21755 failed: Operation not permitted

Thank-you

Comment: (1) when did the error message show? (2) is your box functioning as a firewall/router or are you trying to transp-proxy traffic coming out of the box?

Comment: Im trying to send data from my local desktop ubuntu computer transparently through a proxy

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your rule is too restrictive.

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner Mark -m tcp -j REDIRECT --to-ports 9040 
iptables -A OUTPUT -m --uid-owner Mark -j DROP
```

The first rule redirects *all* ***TCP*** traffic to port 9040, without trying to discern whether it is something proxy-able (e.g., HTTP) or non-proxy-able (e.g., SSH).

The second rule drops *all* traffic, TCP, UDP, whathaveyou.

You should delete the second rule, and set the `OUTPUT` chain's policy to `ACCEPT`. That will allow all traffic to go through. (Although it will not fix the problem of non-proxy-able traffic gets redirected to the proxy).